# can not create a table in database with libpq in C

Tags: c, database, postgresql, libpq

I created a c function that create a table on my postgresql db. here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

PGconn *connection;
PGresult  *re;

void create_table(){
        re= PQexec(connection, "SELECT to_regclass('fp_stores_data')");
        if(!re){
                PQclear(re);

                re = PQexec(connection ,"CREATE TABLE test(name VARCHAR(3))");

                if(PQresultStatus(re)==PGRES_COMMAND_OK){
                        printf("table created!");
                }else{
                        printf("failed to create table!");
                }
        }else{
                printf("table was created befor!");
        }
        PQclear(re);
}


int main() {
        connection = PQconnectdb("user=username password=123 dbname=projectdb");
        create_table();
        PQfinish(connection);
        return 0;
}
```

but every time I run the program it print `failed to create table!` and there will be nothing in database with that table name.

Comment: You should print `PQerrorMessage(connection)` when you fail, which will give you more information than just failed.

Comment: what does this function return? or print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PQresultErrorMessage` to get the error text for the SQL you executed, eg:

```
printf("%s\n", PQresultErrorMessage(re));
```

Or `PQerrorMessage` to get the error text for any error associated with your connection, eg:

```
printf("%s\n", PQerrorMessage(connection));
```

The postgresql documentation of these functions is here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html

Comment: thanks! I understand that the problem is in connection to the database.